# PostgreSQL SSL setup DigitalOcean

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

I am trying to connect pgAdmin to digitalOcean. However I am getting this error:
[image]

I add the certificate but digital ocean didn't provided me a key file.
Where could I find it?

This Is how I add the certificate file.

[image]

Thank you,

Jonathan Prieto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the certificate that DigitalOcean provided is for the “Root certificate” field.

It is to verify the server, not to authenticate the client.

With the default configuration of `libpq` you don't need the certificate at all, and SSL is used only to encrypt the communication.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create this private key with `openssl` command.

Unfortunately client certificate setup is not documented in the PostgreSQL official documentation.

The best documentation that I have found is the following:
https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/ssl-certificate-authentication-postgresql-docker-containers.

You should try to adapt "Step 4: Generating the Client Key and Certificate" to your configuration.